# Memory Leak from use of DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms, timer

so I'm not the greatest at analyzing memory leaks but from what I can tell I have located one.

I am using a timer to check if something is connected and when I comment out my timer my memory leak goes away.

The timer code is very simple, like this:

```
private System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer EmbdAttachTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
EmbdAttachTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(AttachTimer_Elapsed);
EmbdAttachTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
EmbdAttachTimer.Start();
```

The code for the eventhandler "AttachTimer_Elapsed" is as follows:

```
void AttachTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bAttached = isUnitAttached(); // simple check of USB connection
UpdateCnctStatText(); // some calls to UI elements to update them with "connected" or "not connected"
}
```

The code for isUnitAttached() makes a call to a library driven function that checks for an MSP430 processor on the other end of the usb line.

```
bool IsUnitAttached
{ 
   bSuccess = usbI_MSP430.Connect(); 
   if (!bSuccess) 
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect."); 
       return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Pretty confused by this, I've look all over and I was previously using a delegate to run the UpdateCnctStatText function but changed to a DispatcherTimer hoping it would solve my problems but it made no difference.

Comment: Not sure what the check of USB connection entails, but do you properly close connection in `isUnitAttached()` with `using` or at least `finally` statement?

Comment: The leaky code will be in one of `isUnitAttached()` or `UpdateCnctStatText()` (or in something they call).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!  The code for isUnitAttached() makes a call to a library driven function that checks for an MSP430 processor on the other end of the usb line.  Here is the code:
{
bSuccess = usbI_MSP430.Connect();
if (!bSuccess)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect.");
   return false;
}
return true;
}
Also, don't comment on the horrific code style this is a fix-me-up project that I am working on and a lot of the code is REALLY ugly :)

Comment: I was hoping that would box out like the original post, not sure how to put code excerpts in comment

Comment: Just checked and it's definitely my usbI_MSP430.Connect() function that is leaking memory but that's a call to a .dll driven function. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You're connecting on every timer Elapsed and not disconnecting?  Sounds like a good candidate for a leak...

Comment: Like Peter says, where's the disconnect? Normally methods  that connect to hardware either return a handle that you can pass to some kind of close method, or have a matching disconnect method, or both.

Comment: Well, for one the leak happens even if it doesn't successfully connect - in which case disconnecting would be useless.  This function only returns a boolean whether or not there is a connection to the MSP430 microprocessor I'm looking for.